# How to pass a JSON-formatted string from Excel VBA as argument to a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, json, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in MySQL that reads a JSON array of objects and insert the objects in a JSON column of a temp table:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_json $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProcedure(IN myjson TEXT)
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE qryStmt TEXT;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable(update_key int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, update_data JSON, PRIMARY KEY(update_key));
WHILE i < JSON_LENGTH(myjson) DO
    SET qryStmt = CONCAT("INSERT INTO tempTable VALUES(DEFAULT, (JSON_EXTRACT('", myjson,"','$[",i,"]')))");
    PREPARE stmt FROM qryStmt;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The Stored Procedure works fine when I call the procedure in MySQL `>CALL myProcedure('[{"firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Cruise", "occupation": "Actor"}, {"firstname": "Al", "lastname": "Pacino", "occupation": "Actor"}]');`, it reads the string as separate JSON objects and inserts them as records in the table.

[image]

I also have the following Sub in Excel VBA that intends to call the stored procedure, passing a JSON-formatted array of objects to the stored procedure:

```
Sub proc_jason()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim strConnection, jsonString As String

Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

jsonString = "[{""firstname"": ""Tom"", ""lastname"": ""Cruise"", ""occupation"": ""Actor""}, " _
             & "{""firstname"": ""Alfredo"", ""lastname"": ""Pacino"", ""occupation"": ""Actor""}]"

strConnection = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver}; Server=[IP]; Database=[Db]; user=[usr]; PWD=[pwd]"
objConnection.Open strConnection
         
With objRecordset
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .Open "CALL myProcedure('" & jsonString & "');", objConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdStoredProc
End With

objRecordset.Close
Set objRecordset = Nothing
objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

The Sub returns the following error:

[image]

I've seen posts calling a MySQL stored procedure using the `Command` object:

```
With objCommand
    .ActiveConnection = objConnection
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "CALL myProcedure('" & jsonString & "');"
    .Execute
End With
```

But I still get the same error message. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that `[[{` is correct. Please check what and how many brackets are required.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it, the error message is still the same. As per the syntax in MySQL it should be one bracket. `>CALL myProcedure('[{json-array}]');`

Comment: Maybe try using a parameterised call - eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40831427/478884

Comment: Add some `vbCrLf`s in your json. It'll maybe give you a better error message.

Comment: Tim, I changed the Sub using a parameterised call. One question,  I understand the third parameter of the objCommand.CreateParameter instruction is the length of the string input, correct? I input a random 500 number, how do I define this parameter when I don't know the length of the string? There is no error message when I run the Sub but the stored procedure doesn't run, no table is created as expected.

Comment: Sam, added vbCrLF, the error message is `Error: (-2147217900) [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.3.38-MariaDB]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL myProcedure('[{"firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Cruise", "occupation": "...' at line 1   16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parameter length to the json string length.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "mysqlu" ' dsn
    
    Const json = "a json string"
    
    With New ADODB.Command
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "myProcedure"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, Len(json), json)
        MsgBox .Execute.GetString
    End With
    con.Close
  
End Sub

CREATE PROCEDURE `myProcedure`(IN myjson TEXT)
BEGIN
    select myjson as result;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sam and CPD1802 inputs the final Sub that worked is the following:

```
Sub demo()

On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver}; Server=ip; Database=db; user=usr; password=psw"
    
    Const json = "[{""firstname"": ""Tom"", ""lastname"": ""Cruise"", ""occupation"": ""Actor""}, " _
             & "{""firstname"": ""Alfredo"", ""lastname"": ""Pacino"", ""occupation"": ""Actor""}, " _
             & "{""firstname"": ""Winston"", ""lastname"": ""Churchill"", ""occupation"": ""Politician""}]"
    
    With New ADODB.Command
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "myProcedure"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("myjson", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, Len(json), json)
        MsgBox .Execute.GetString
    End With
    conn.Close
    
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    
End Sub
```

No error message but still the Stored Procedure did not insert the records in the table. I dropped TEMPORARY in the lines of the Stored Procedure:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempTable;
CREATE TABLE tempTable(update_key int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, update_data JSON, PRIMARY KEY(update_key));
```

And now it works, for some reason using TEMPORARY TABLE when calling a Stored Procedure from Excel VBA doesn't work.

Comment: A [TEMPORARY table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) is visible only to the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed.

Comment: I ran the Sub while logged into a MySQL session, the temp table existing but empty, neither the table was dropped after running the Sub, nor were the records inserted. I don't think the sub executes the Stored Procedure with TEMPORARY TABLES.

Comment: The temp table in your session is a different table to the one in the adodb session even though they may have the same name. Microsoft sql have global temp tables accessible across sessions but I don't think mysql does.